# Rails 4 attr_accessible alternative

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was following rails tutorial on how to use CRUD but this tutorial was using Rails 3.  But because Rails 4 dropped the attr_accessible method I can't get my database to work.  I am trying to create a simple blog post with a database that has a :title and content field, how would I implement this in the

Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base file

Side question: Do you recommend any good tutorials where they create an app using rails (like a blog etc) I can follow.

Thanks you

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4 you typically permit parameters at the controller level rather than defining access control at the model level.

```
  def create
    @user = user.create user_params
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(
      :name,
      :age,
      :shoe_size
    )
  end
```

I recommend reading Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial. It's free to read online, or worth every penny for the printed version.

Comment: When you say I should permit parameters at the controller level should I still be in class Post < ActiveRecord::Base? Sorry for the stupid questions I'm new to rails